# How to arrange or format the table results in Oracle SQL Plus

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I started learning Oracle and I've been gone through different types of examples. But from the beginning I have an issue that how can we arrange the retrieve table in well formatted view. I am using SQL Plus.

[image]

I attached a image of the way I get the output. I want the output table in a proper table view ( *Organized columns and rows* ).

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name,
                i.company.company AS stock_name,
                i.company.current_price AS cur_price,
                i.company.last_dividend AS last_devident,
                i.company.earning_pershare AS eps
  FROM client_table_c c, TABLE (c.investments) i
```

Comment: The one who downvoted please explain why. Provide some reason since I'm really new to oracle, but not to stackoverflow

Comment: set lin 2000  pages 0(replace with higher number if you want heading) are few of the commands we use and for formatting column refer below link
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following to have the output in a single line and in a more formatted way

```
SET LINESIZE 32000;
SET PAGESIZE 40000;
```

For more formatting options, see [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch4.htm)

Comment: @Ramesh Glad to know that I am of some help.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL*Plus, there's the `COLUMN` command (can be abbreviated to `COL`) which allows you to format *columns*. For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id     number,
  3     name   varchar2(50));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL> col name format a15
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ---------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

See? NAME column is now shortened.

For much more info, have a look at [Formatting SQL Plus reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#CHDBEAAB) (feel free to read the whole SQL Plus document).

P.S. I'm glad you use SQL Plus. It requires you to actually *know* what you're doing. GUI tools allow you to click here & click there, not really knowing what's behind that click and what result you can expect. However, once you get used to use Oracle, switch to - for example - SQL Developer (a free GUI tool by Oracle) which displays results of your queries in a more appropriate manner, without the need to manually adjust the output in order to make it readable).

Comment: This is even a good one. But It's hard to format each and everycolumn by mentioning the column name. Anyway thankyou. I found the answer here